# ADF Data flow 'Source' activity - data preview error

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to Filter the last modified folders in Source activity in ADF Data Flow using the start time UTC 'subDays(currentUTC(), 1)' and end time UTC 'currentUTC()', with the following wildcard pattern - 'subfolder/subfolder/**/*.parquet' and I am encountering this error - at Source 'Source1': Path does not resolve to any file(s). Please make sure the file/folder exists and is not hidden. At the same time, ensure special characters are not included in the file/folder name, for example, a name starting with _."
When I remove 'Filter by last modified', the data preview works and successfully reads the files. What could be the reason for it not working when I use the 'Filter by last modified' functions?

[image: Data preview error]

[image: Wildcard pattern]

[image: Filter by last modified]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expressions in the start and end time will give the time in the `UTC` timezone. So, as per the `UTC`, it won't find any modified files and that's why the below error occurred.

[image]

To avoid this error, give your timezone in the expression.

**Start time:** `subDays(currentUTC('<your timezone>'),1)`

**End time:**  `currentUTC('<your timezone>')`

Also, check the **`Allow no files found`** option in the source settings. This option avoids the error, if no files found in the specific location and gives no data on the data preview.

[image]